# Using a variable in more than one funciton?

Tags: function, variables, process, vhdl, modelsim

it is probably because of me being newbe. Anyways, I want to define some variables to use in more than one function (like global variables in C). I decided to go with shared variables but it gives me the error `Cannot reference shared variable "x" inside pure function "y"`. If I define the variable in a process, then it initializes(erases the value) every process activation.

```
Architecture SV_example of example is

shared variable temp:std_logic_vector(18 downto 0):= "0000000000000000000";
SIGNAL gct: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(18 DOWNTO 0);

    function register_adder( load_value:std_logic ) return std_logic_vector is      
    begin   
        for i in size downto 0 loop 
            temp(i) := load_value;
        end loop;
     return temp;            
    end register_adder;


    p1 : process (CLK)
    begin
      if rising_edge(CLK) then
        gct <= register_loader('1'); 
   end if;
   end process;
end SV_example;
```

Comment: I put an answer to how to get rid of the error.  But I'm not sure of your goal here.  Your example above does not need `temp`, since you use the return value from the function.  Post a more complete example and we can help analyze your use case better.

Comment: You are right. Example above is not clear to point my requirement. I just need a global variable to reach from every function in architecture.

Comment: What do you need a architecture wide variable as opposed to a `signal`?  What are you trying to accomplish by sharing information through a `shared variable`.  If you need some sort of state information, I suggest looking at `protected` types in VHDL-2002 and later.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Something about encapsulation is gonna be more useful for future works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VHDL (at least with VHDL '93 and later), functions are `pure` by default.  A `pure` function is one that has no side effects.  It depends only on its inputs, with no dependency on (non-static) outside information.

So, your fix is to declare the function `impure`.  I had to do some editing to your example to make it an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  The fix:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity example is
  port
  (
    CLK : in std_logic
  );
end entity example;

Architecture SV_example of example is

shared variable temp:std_logic_vector(18 downto 0):= "0000000000000000000";
SIGNAL gct: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(18 DOWNTO 0);

    impure function register_adder( load_value:std_logic ) return std_logic_vector is
    begin
        for i in temp'length-1 downto 0 loop
            temp(i) := load_value;
        end loop;
     return temp;
    end register_adder;
begin


    p1 : process (CLK)
    begin
      if rising_edge(CLK) then
        gct <= register_adder('1');
   end if;
   end process;
end SV_example;
```

Note this works only in VHDL '93.  The use of a `shared variable` changes significantly in VHDL '02 and later.

One final note.  Shared variables generally are not synthesizable (the only example I can think of is the inference model for a RAM).  Shared variables are usually only for general purpose use in hardware or testbench modeling.

Answer (score 1):

Shared variable often goes with protected types, which can handle encapsulation of data.  An example using protected type is shown below:

```
architecture SV_example of example is

  signal gct           : std_logic_vector(18 downto 0);

  type temp_t is protected
    impure function register_adder(load_value : std_logic) return std_logic_vector;
  end protected;

  type temp_t is protected body
    variable temp : std_logic_vector(18 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    impure function register_adder(load_value : std_logic) return std_logic_vector is
    begin
      for i in temp'range loop
        temp(i) := load_value;
      end loop;
      return temp;
    end function;
  end protected body;

  shared variable temp_sv : temp_t;

begin

  p1 : process (CLK)
  begin
    if rising_edge(CLK) then
      gct <= temp_sv.register_adder('1');
    end if;
  end process;

end SV_example;
```

For access to the internal `temp` data, a function `get_temp` can be written, if needed.